# Redirection to https almost working, but not quite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a site and i would like to have following redirections:

```
1. http://mysite.net     => https://www.mysite.com
2. http://www.mysite.net => https://www.mysite.com
3. http://mysite.com     => https://www.mysite.com
4. http://www.mysite.com => https://www.mysite.com
```

I've achieved 1, 2 and 3, but I am having troubles with the 4th one, because of "too many redirections". This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

# Use PHP5.3 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

# Send all traffic of main domain to subdirectory

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/mysite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/mysite.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sites/mysite.com/index.php [L]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant the magical solution IS:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

# Use PHP5.3 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

# Send all traffic of main domain to subdirectory

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/mysite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/mysite.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sites/mysite.com/index.php [L]
```